# How to wake up "getline" over cin in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, cin, getline

I have one thread (THREAD A):

```
while (true) {
    if (isOpen)) {
        break;
    }
    string line = "";
    getline(cin,line);
    std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

On start program `isOpen = true;`, in another thread (THREAD B) I set `isOpen` to false.

I want to ask you, how to wake up THREAD A, which is sleeaping over getline?

My idea is sent empty string to cin, but how?

Thank you for your help.

FULL EXAMPLE CODE:

```
using namespace std;
#include <thread> 

bool isOpen = true;

void test() {
    Sleep(10000); //sleep for 10s
    isOpen = false; //break loop
}

int main() {
    std::thread* _t = new std::thread(test); //start thread B
    while (true) {
        if (isOpen==true) {
            break;
        }
        string line = "";
        getline(cin,line);
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not compiled this code, i am writing from mobile, there can be some syntax errors,...

Comment: @RawN I add full example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in case your `Sleep` function is supposed to be `sleep` from `unistd.h`, notice that it counts in seconds, not in ms.
Notice that thread A would probably not reach the `getline` func, since it immediately breaks in the `if(isOpen==true){break;}`.